# Plupload: perform custom check before starting upload

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, plupload

I have an MVC 5 view with a form and a plupload file uploader section. Upload is triggered by a button on the form. I have no problem uploading file chunks to the server and setting the parameters to the query string and all, but what I do have a problem with is starting the upload **only after a custom sanity check has been performed**.

Here's what I have tried:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
 runtimes: 'html5',
 drop_element: 'upload',
 browse_button: 'browse',
 url: "../UploadFile",
 chunk_size: "1024kb",
 multipart_params: { "uid": "uid", "chunk": "chunk", "chunks": "chunks", "name": "name" },
 init: {
  PostInit: function(file) {
   document.getElementById("filelist").innerHTML = "";
   document.getElementById('submit-all').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("infoPopup").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById('submit-all').enabled = false;
    var uuid = Math.uuidFast();
    document.getElementById("uid").value = uuid;
    uploader.settings.multipart_params = { uid: uuid, chunk: file.chunk, chunks: file.chunks, name: file.name };
    if (checkReq) {
     uploader.start();
    }
    return false;
   };
  },
```

The crucial part here is this:

```
if(checkReq){ 
  uploader.start();
}
```

"checkReq" is my custom sanity check script that verifies that form values are not nonsensical (e.g. single form entries might be perfectly valid while in combination they are simply wrong, etc.).

So the above does not prevent the upload, the check script is not even fired, Firebug console output shows no error.

Since googling tells me that there is also a "BeforeUpload" event, I tried this:

```
BeforeUpload: function(up, file) {
    if (checkReq) {
        up.stop();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
},
```

Which also does not seem to fire at all.

Edit: Next attempt, I put the call to my checkReq fuction into BeforeUpload in "preinit", which *should* fire before any chunking etc is done, so before the upload is prepared. This also failed although I have no idea why it does not fire:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes: 'html5',
    drop_element: 'upload',
    browse_button: 'browse',
    url: "../UploadFile",
    chunk_size: "1024kb",
    multipart_params: { "uid": "uid", "chunk": "chunk", "chunks": "chunks", "name": "name" },

    preinit: {
        BeforeUpload: function (up) {
            if (checkReq) {
                uploader.stop();
                uploader.splice(0, uploader.files.length);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    },

    init: {
        PostInit: function(file) {
...
```

I had used "dropzone.js" before, and my script worked fine with that but I found that I needed chunked uploads so I had to move to plupload and now my script is being ignored.

Could someone please tell me where I am being stupid here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it solved.
It's a nasty, ugly hack, but it works:

- Made the "actual" submit/upload button hidden
- Made a second button that acts as pre-submit button with onclick function
- onclick function calls checkReq and if that returns true, the function calls the click() function of the "actual" submit/upload button

Like I said: nasty but it works.